# Graphing digraphs with the following vertex set

Tags: discrete-mathematics, computer-science

[image]

Just want to make sure I did this correctly.. I think I did part **a)** correctly? Here is my solution for part **a)**
[image]

Not sure how to do **b)** and **c)** though. Any advice would be great. Thanks in advance

Comment: You’ve put the edges between the right vertices, but this is a *digraph* (directed graph), so each of the edges should have a direction associated with it. For instance, $d$ goes from $w$ to $z$, while $f$ goes from $z$ to $w$. The adjacency matrix will be a $4\times 4$ matrix, and the incidence matrix will be a $4\times 6$ matrix; in each of them the entries will all be either $1,-1$, or $0$. What do you know so far about adjacency and incidence matrices?

Comment: So my graph is correct then, I just need to make sure to put arrows($\rightarrow$) to indicate which direction each is traveling right?

Comment: Yes, that’s right.

Comment: So would the adjacency matrix look like this : $A = w[ 0  1 1 1]$                                              ..                                                                             $x[ 1  1 0 0] $                                   ..                                                                             $y[ 0  0 0 0]$                                          ..                                                                             $z[ 0  0 1 0]$

Comment: Idk how to make a matrix in LaTeX by the way but assume that that is in matrix form.

Comment: So would the adjacency matrix look like this :  $A = $ \begin{array}{ccc}
0 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
1 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \end{array}

Comment: Yes, that’s correct. (You can get an actual matrix with `\pmatrix{...}`, where the dots indicate elements separated in the same way as in an array.)

Comment: Ok cool. How would I get a $4 \times 6$ matrix when solving the incidence? Wouldn't it be a $4 \times 7$ matrix because ${a,b,c,d,e,f,g} = 7 $ ?

Comment: Can I use $0$ instead of $-1$ ?

Comment: No, in the incidence matrix you need to use signed entries in order to keep track of the directions of the edges. In the adjacency matrix that’s not necessary, because the arrangement of the matrix itself gives you the direction.

Comment: can you provide the solution to $c)$ because my book doesn't have any $(-1)$'s any of the incidence solutions so I'm confused.. But I ended up getting: \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 0 \\ 1 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 1 \end{bmatrix}

Comment: Also I'm assuuming $w,x,y,z \times a,b,c,d,e,f,g$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The trickiest part is the incidence matrix. You have a row for each vertex and a column for each edge. If $v$ is a vertex and $e$ is an edge, the $\langle v,e\rangle$ entry is $0$ if $e$ is not incident at $v$, $1$ if $e$ enters is $v$, $-1$ if $e$ leaves $v$ (I inadvertently reversed this in a comment that I’ve now erased), and (at least by the definition that I know) $2$ if $e$ is a loop at $v$. Thus, we get the following matrix:

$$\begin{bmatrix}
1&-1&0&-1&-1&1&0\\
-1&1&2&0&0&0&0\\
0&0&0&0&1&0&1\\
0&0&0&1&0&-1&-1
\end{bmatrix}$$

Comment: I understand now. Thanks so much Brian. So for loops it always be $2$ ?

Comment: @user3325915: You’re very welcome. That’s the convention that I know for loops, both for undirected and for directed graphs. It’s conceivable that there are also other conventions in use for digraphs; this is not a field in which I’m expert.

Comment: also for $y$ shouldn't the last $1$ be positive? It has edge  $e \rightarrow y $as well as edge $g$ $\rightarrow y$

Comment: @user3325915: It should indeed; thanks for catching that.

Comment: Wouldn't have known unless you taught me in the first place haha but thanks again.